# Mapping transient characteristics from S domain to Z domain

Tags: control-theory, stability-theory, discrete-time

The $s$ and $z$ domains are linked by the expression $z = e^{sT}$, where $s$ is the Laplace variable and $T$ is the sampling period. However, I have found no rigorous method that attempts to derive all the well-developed characteristics for the LTI continuous systems such as absolute stability, relative stability, damping, overshoot, etc for the discrete systems in the $z$ too. In other words, while complex variables in the $s$ plane are mathematically mapped into the $z$ plane by the mentioned expression, how can we prove that the transient system characteristics are mapped in a similar manner; particularly  knowing that there is no bijective mapping of the system poles and zeros from $s$ domain to $z$ domain. Can anyone give me some insight please?

Comment: The correspondence between continuous- and disctete-time is explained in any text book on discrete-time control systems. Same thing regarding why the unit disc is the region of stability for such systems.

Comment: Thanks @KBS, I did some modifications to my question.